# Gitlab CI: Why next stage is allowed to run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have one gitlab CI file like this

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
  when: manual

deploy-bridge:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: tests/ci-downstream
```

What I understand is that the deploy-bridge stage should not be run unless the manual build-job is run successfully. But it is not the case here. Is this normal?

> Jobs in the same stage run in parallel. Jobs in the next stage run
> after the jobs from the previous stage complete successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not defining your `deploy-bridge` job as a [`dependent`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) job, or that it [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) another job to finish first, so it can run right away as soon as it reaches the stage. Since the previous stage is all `manual` jobs, GitLab CI/CD sort of interprets it as 'done', at least enough so that other stages can start.

Since it doesn't look like you're uploading the compiled code from `build-job` as an [`artifact`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts), we can't use the `dependencies` keyword here. All that keyword does is control which jobs' dependencies *this* job needs, but if it needs the artifacts of a prior job, that job will need to run and finish successfully for *this* job to start. Also, by default all available artifacts from all prior jobs will be downloaded and available for all jobs in the pipeline. The `dependencies` keyword can also be used to limit which artifacts *this* job actually needs. However, if there are no artifacts available in the job we "depend" on, it will throw an error. Luckily there's another keyword we can use.

The `needs` keyword controls the "flow" of the pipeline, so much so that if a job anywhere in the pipeline (even in the last of say 1,000 stages) had `needs: []` it will run as soon as the pipeline starts (and as soon there is an available runner). We can use `needs` here to make the pipeline flow the way you need.

```yaml
...
deploy-bridge:
  stage: deploy
  needs: ['build-job']
  trigger:
    project: tests/ci-downstream
```

Now, the `deploy-bridge` job won't run until the `build-job` has finished successfully. If `build-job` fails, `deploy-bridge` will be skipped.

One other use for `needs` is that it has the same functionality as `dependencies`, in that it can control what artifacts are downloaded in which jobs, but it won't fail if the "needed" jobs don't have artifacts at all.

Both `dependencies` and `needs` accept an empty array which equates to 'don't download any artifacts' and for `needs`, run as soon as a runner is available.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Don't jobs in sequential stages run in that sequence as defined in "stages" part?